# Lexis Nexis people search

Tags: java

I have been asked to use **LexisNexis services** for the verification of the users in the java application we are developing.

> A user opens up the registration page and his/her verification is done
>   through LexisNexis services.

And thats it. I have read [this](http://www.lexisnexis.com/Webserviceskit) and [this](http://www.lexisnexis.com/Webserviceskit/v2_0beta/default.aspx) article about it. Still I am not sure if it does what exactly I am looking for i.e. verification/searching people.

The idea is to use Social Security Number for the verification. So, can we really use LexisNexis for the verification of people or is it something else I should be looking for? It'd be nice to have some direction.

Comment: second link can't reachable if not have account...

Comment: I think I've found something. But might need more information. Anyway good progress. [LexisNexis InstantVerify](http://www.lexisnexis.com/risk/solutions/instant-identity-verification.aspx)